# Running Jersey Servlet on Jetty - Error: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, jetty, jersey

When I am trying to run my Jersey Servlet on jetty with `mvn jetty:run` I get back the error:

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
2011-07-15 20:03:05.736:WARN:/server:unavailable
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
```

It must be something really simple, please help me out. I feel like I am doomed to fail developing a simple JAX-RS HelloWorld!!!

When I open http://localhost:8080/server/ (server being the project name) I get back "Hello World!" when I should only get something back opening http://localhost:8080/rest/test/ it should say "hello". Is this an old servlet in my jetty even though I perform the mvn jetty:run on my project folder?

**Folder Structure**

[image]

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.e.api</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**HelloWorldResource.java**

```
package com.e.api;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.ProduceMime;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/test")
public class HelloWorldResource {

 @GET
 @Produces("text/html") //Modified after comment from @ProduceMime
 public String getMessage( ) {
  return "hello";
 }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.e.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>server Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.6</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>server</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Maven 1 Repository (legacy)</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/1</url>
            <layout>legacy</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

**mvn jetty:build -e**

```
PS C:\Users\Dom\work\server> mvn jetty:run -e
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building server Maven Webapp
[INFO]    task-segment: [jetty:run]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing jetty:run
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 10 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Dom\work\server\src\test\resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [jetty:run {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: server Maven Webapp
[INFO] Webapp source directory = C:\Users\Dom\work\server\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = C:\Users\Dom\work\server\target\classes
2011-07-15 23:17:11.868:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
[INFO] Context path = /server
[INFO] Tmp directory =  determined at runtime
[INFO] Web defaults = org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = C:\Users\Dom\work\server\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = C:\Users\Dom\work\server\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Starting jetty 6.1.26 ...
2011-07-15 23:17:11.937:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
2011-07-15 23:17:12.026:INFO::No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
15.07.2011 23:17:12 com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.e.api
15.07.2011 23:17:12 com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.8 06/24/2011 12:17 PM'
15.07.2011 23:17:12 com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules <init>
SCHWERWIEGEND: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
2011-07-15 23:17:12.806:WARN:/server:unavailable
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.

        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1298)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318
)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:736)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:115)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:454)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:396)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:210)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.jav
a:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
2011-07-15 23:17:12.877:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** After some discussion, we've come to the conclusion that the java source file is in the wrong location and isn't being compiled.

Comment: The next thing I'd have to check is whether your class is actually being compiled and put in the right place for it to be part of the war that jetty is running.

Comment: Oh, hmm... where did you get @ProduceMime from? That looks like a very old form of @Produces. You seem to be using Jersey 1.8. I don't think ProduceMime should even be there. Try @Produces instead.

Comment: Interestingly when I modify the package declaration in the HelloWorldResource to something completely different (for example org.example) eclipse does mark that line with an error telling me to either change the package declaration or to create the package? Is it the default behaviour of jetty to create a "Hello World!" page I see when I go to `http://localhost:8080/server/`?

Comment: I right clicked the project -> Maven -> Update Project configuration which gives back: `16.07.11 09:07:35 MESZ: [WARN] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin is missing. @ line 38, column 12` ... `16.07.11 09:07:35 MESZ: Adding resource folder /server/src/main/resources`

Comment: Ah, you're having trouble with the packaging, maybe? If your HelloWorldResource class declares `package org.example;` then it should live at <project dir>/src/main/java/org/example/HelloWorldResource.java. When compiled, it should end up in target/classes, and that's where jetty will load it from.

Comment: As you can see from the folder structure my HelloWorldResouce lives at `server/src/main/resources/com/e/api`, the `org.example` was to illustrate that eclipse basically does not mind what package I declare by not compaining about an incorrect package declaration. Before I always got a message telling me to either change the package declaration or to move it to the new package. I tried that to see if there might be the problem. Do you have suggestions on how to fix things from here? Thank you for your help so far, I appreciate this so much!

Comment: I've copied your three files into a new project, and (with minor changes) it works for me. If you have git, you can try it out yourself: 1: `git clone git@github.com:zzantozz/testbed tmp` 2: `cd tmp/basic-jersey` 3: `mvn jetty:run` The only real change I made was to add the maven compiler plugin and set the source and target values to 1.6. I'm not sure how you were able to compile without that--which might be your problem. Maybe your class wasn't being compiled.

Comment: Ah, problem solved. All java files need to be in src/main/java. Only non-compiled things go in src/main/resources: things like properties files and spring and hibernate config files.